# Partition Function and Expected value of dipole moment

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, partition-function

I have a cubic lattice, and I am trying to find the partition function and the expected value of the dipole moment. I represent the dipole moment as a unit vector pointing to one the 8 corners of the system. I know nothing about the average dipole moment , but I do know that the mean-field Hamiltonian is given by:

p$_i \cdot \langle p \rangle$ =H(p).

If the dipole, was oriented along all possible directions of the cubic lattice, then I would have performed an integration over spherical coordinates obtaining the usual Langevin function. Now in this scenario, I am a bit hesitant because I know nothing about the direction of the average dipole moment. Shall I assume a haphazard direction and then proceed algebraically for the summation over the 8 possible directions?

I have thought of a possible solution. Instead of treating dipoles in all 3 directions simultaneously, we could treat each direction separately, thus creating 3 equations which are easy to solve. Analytically we have:

$\frac{{\sum_{i}p_{ix}{e^{p_{ix}\cdot \langle p_x \rangle}}}}{\sum_i e^{p_{ix}\langle p_x \rangle}}=\langle p_x \rangle$.

In this case due to symmetry the summations are easy to calculate yielding that $\langle p_x \rangle$=tanh($\frac{\sqrt(3) \langle p_x \rangle}{3KT}$)

Due to the fact that we have a cubic lattice then for all direction we obtain the same solution

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your proposed solution assumes that the components of the dipole moment are independent of each other, but this may or may not be a good assumption. In particular if the magnitude of the dipole is fixed then the components will not be independent

Comment: Hmm. Fair point. Do you any proposals for that?